# angular 2 Http observable input update in child but don't want to affects other components

Tags: http, angular, input, components, observable

I have a parent component with a people property. It uses a Service to get people Observable .

Then I have several children components. Everyone has @Input people from parent component. (To avoid http request on every child)

I would like to modify people array in each Child component without affecting the others (parent component and other child component)

It would be something like a new Observable copy or get data from observable.

**I need the initial value of people in all components, but then I need to modify for each one.**

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the people object to be an `Observable` in the child components? If this is not the case, you might want to change your code a bit. Instead of passing the `Observable` to the child components, just pass along the initial data via `@Input()`-Binding.